# Change the month in the second date picker based on the first in angular date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I change the month of my second datepicker dynamically to display as the selected month based on the first date picker selection?But it is showing the current date.
Example:
I selected 15-10-2104 from the first time picker.Hence the second date picker should open with the date starting from 15-10-2014.All the previous dates should be disabled.

I'm using angular bootstrap datepicker and heres the code:

```
<label>Start Date <span class="required"></span></label>

<div class="seldate startdate calender-icon nopadding">
    <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
           ng-model="info.startDate"
           required
           name="startDate" tabindex="4" 
           placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
           is-open="startDate.open"
           ng-click="startDate.open = true"
           min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
           close-text="Close" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label>End Date <span class="required"></span></label>

    <div class="seldate startdate calender-icon nopadding">
        <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
               ng-model="info.endDate"
               required

               name="endDate" tabindex="5"
               placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
               is-open="endDate.open"
               ng-click="endDate.open = true"
               min-date="scheduleInfo.startDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
               date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
               close-text="Close" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-change in the first datepicker to set min-date in the second datepicker.

ng-change="setMinEndDate()"

```
$scope.setMinEndDate = function() {
    var endDate = angular.copy($scope.info.startDate);
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
    $scope.scheduleInfo.startDate = endDate;
};
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I need to disable all the previous dates in the second date picker when I select the first